# Wrong range version in manifest.mf

Tags: maven, maven-3, manifest, maven-dependency-plugin

I'm including a dependence in a Maven project giving a Range:

```
<dependencyManagement> 
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.project.name</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifact</artifactId>
    <version>[3.53,)</version>
</dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The deploy starts and maven looks for the dependencies on a Nexus server, downloading every version since 3.53 to the last available Relase/Snapshot (this is ok for us, that is what the ranges are for!). Just to make it clear, let's say that the last version of this package is 3.56.4-SNAPSHOT

But when I deploy the package, I see that in the MANIFEST.MF the ranges has been changed in:

```
com.project.name.artifact;version="[3.56,4)"
```

Instead, I wish I could conserve:

```
com.project.name.artifact;version="[3.53,4)"
```

It's a problem for me because I need to install this jar on a server where it's not taken for granted that the package 3.56 will be available.

I have tried to change the ranges by setting, for example:
`[3.53,4)`
`[3.53.0,4)`
`[3.53.0,)`
`[3.53.0,4.0.0)`
`[3.53.0,4.0.0]`

with no success.

Is there a way to force maven to set the specific ranges defined in the pom.xml file also in the MANIFEST.MF?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Version ranges are not really recommended. What problem are you trying to solve with version ranges? Maybe we can find a more fitting Maven-like solution for that.

Comment: Hi. We are developing some application made by different packages, in different environments (Adobe AEM instances). Let's say, the ```Package A``` depends on ```Package B ver. 3.53.0```. For any reason, the ```Package B``` could be re-deployed an installed on an instance, so I will generate the ```package B ver. 3.53.1``` and install it on Adobe AEM. The ```package A``` will not work anymore since he couldn't find the version ```package B ver. 3.53.0``` anymore, since it has been replaced with the version 3.53.1, this is why we need to set the ranges. Thank you.

Comment: Maven versions are purely a compile time thing. It does not restrict or control what you do at runtime. So if you compile against 3.53 and load 3.56 at runtime, there is no problem (as long as the classes in 3.53 and 3.56 are doing the same thing). Or do you somehow evaluate the manifest.mf at runtime to manage versions?

Comment: I think that Adobe AEM looks if the right version has been installed, and it does it  taking this information in the manifest file.

Comment: I would check if this is really the case.